# How to explain the pronunciations of brother and breakfast

Tags: letters-of-the-alphabet

My nephew is 4 and start reading a lot in English,his mother language is not English., he asked me why  the “o” in the word brother is “∧" not "⊃" sorry I can't find how to type the letters, and another one is breakfast, when he was reading it was literally sounded like "break fast", but it's not right,I said just look at the symbolic phonetics,but he still ask me why? How to tell him? Thanks.

Comment: Are these the only two words he's questioning the pronunciation of?

Comment: Yes, for now.but he has very limited vocabulary, I'm not sure if he would have any problems in the future with these type of questions about the 'strange words' again.He use 'strange' to describe the pronunciation of 'breakfast'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare for the floodgates to open. Think about:

- *other* vs *bother*,
- *head* vs *knead*,
- *mint* vs. *pint*,
- *was* vs *has*,
- *most* vs. *cost*,
- *here* vs *there*,
- *now* vs *know*,
- *blood* vs *mood*

and a host of others. And wait until he asks you about words that contain or end with *ough*.

The short answer would be that many vowels, vowel pairs, and letter combinations have **more than one possible pronunciation** (often related to word origin), and that English is simply not a phonetic language where you can look at a word and be sure of its pronunciation. There are legions of exceptions and quirks, like the silent *w* in *answer*, and the way *would* and *wood* are pronounced the same.

As a footnote, congratulations on having such an observant and inquisitive nephew.